# 'method' object has no attribute 'message_content'

Tags: python, discord, bots, attributeerror

Attempting to create a discord bot and I am following the tutorial linked [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UYJDKSah-Ww). I am receiving the following error from line 14:

```
    intents.message_content = True #NOQA
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute 'message_content'
```

Here is my code:

```
from typing import Final
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord import Intents, Client, Message
from responses import get_response

#Step 0: Load our token from somewhere safe
load_dotenv()
#Final decorator makes it so that this cannot be overwritten or have subclasses
TOKEN: Final[str] = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

# Step 1: Bot Setup - activate intents
intents: Intents = Intents.default
intents.message_content = True #NOQA
client: Client = Client(intents=intents)

#Step 2: Message Functionality
async def send_message(message: Message, user_message: str):
    if not user_message:
        print('Message was empty because intents were not enabled... probably')
        return
    
    # The := "Walrus Operator" is used to prompt for input.
    if is_private := user_message[0] == '?':
        user_message = user_message[1:]
    
    try:
        response: str = get_response(user_message)
        await message.author.send(response) if is_private else message.channel.send(response)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

#Step 3: Handling the startup for our bot.
        
@client.event
async def on_ready() -> None:
    print(f"{client.user} is now running")

#Step 4: Handle incoming messages
@client.event
async def on_message(message: Message) -> None:
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    
    username: str = str(message.author)
    user_message: str = message.content
    channel: str = str(message.channel)

    print(f"[{channel}] {username}: '{user_message}")
    await send_message(message, user_message)

# Step 5: Main entry point
def main() -> None:
    client.run(token=TOKEN)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've found this issue in multiple forums with varying solutions dependent on the version of discord.py that's installed. For me, I'm running version 2.3.2. Additionally, I'm running python version 3.12.1.

- I've tried changing intents.message_content to intents.messages.
- Uninstalling and reinstalling the discord library.

Any ideas? Sorry if this is submitted incorrectly, I'm still new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: [`Intents.default`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html) is a method, so call it with parentheses. Remember that those type annotations (`: Intents` in your case) are only as good as the tools you run against them. Python doesn't care that that type annotation is incorrect, so it can mislead you to thinking the error is on another line. If you're going to write type annotations (and I encourage you to do so), you need to run a tool like mypy to validate them

Comment: Silvio didn't quite clarify the issue, but the problem is that the line `intents: Intents = Intents.default` should be `intents: Intents = Intents.default()`

Comment: Silvio, thank you for the advice. I've been studying Python for 7 months now and am just getting into type annotation - I'll have to look into it more.

@nigh_anxiety, thanks for the clarification! That worked.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the solution(s) offered in the comments:

`Intents.default` is a method, so it must be called with parentheses. Errors with type annotations (`: Intents` in Sam's case) are not detected by python's code checker so it can mislead you to thinking the error is on another line. If writing type annotations, a tool like mypy can help detect errors.

Fixed line 13: `intents: Intents = Intents.default()`

All credit to https://stackoverflow.com/users/2288659/silvio-mayolo and https://stackoverflow.com/users/17030540/nigh-anxiety